# Script never seems to register

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have the following simple test asp.net form, with following vb.net load event:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    Dim strScript As String

    strScript = "function MyMsg()"
    strScript += "{"
    strScript += "alert(document.getElementById('TextBox3').value);"
    strScript += "}"
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "MyMsg", strScript, True)

End Sub
```

It simply displays the contexts of a text box in the web page when the script is called.

I then have this button code:

```
Protected Sub Button6_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button6.Click


    If ClientScript.IsStartupScriptRegistered("MyCall") Then
        Me.TextBox3.Text = "My text - registered"
    Else
        Me.TextBox3.Text = "my text NOT registered"
    End If

    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "MyCall", "MyMsg();", True)

End Sub
```

However, the button when clicked on always shows the text NOT registered.  So, the code seems to run ok. It grabs the text from the text box no problme. However, the True part of the code never runs.

Is this a state or scope issue? (or the the fact that the code is only injected one time) that prevents this from running the code block for true?

How can I get the "true" part of the above code to run?

Comment: why not use AJAX to do this instead of the full postback that the asp button causes?

Comment: In fact without any post backs, technically that would not be AJAX anyway without a round trip. So, sure, this can be setup to run 100% browser/script side. The simple basic question remains: How to get the true part of the code to run (or else explain why huge amounts of code examples test for code being register when such code does not work?

Comment: I think the problem with using the full post back is that the page is technically reset everytime the asp button is clicked so any client scripts you previously registered are being wiped clean on each click. A partial post back would keep any script you've already registered intact and allow you to check whether or not the script has been previously registered. If you don't want to implement AJAX or make it all client side then you could always use a session variable, check to see if it is nothing as your `if` instead of checking to see if the script is registered.

Comment: Excellent. If post back re-sets the page then this would explain why I never see the script registered. Strange that tons and tons of examples are written this way and they fail to mention that such code is of no use. Why are tons of examples are all wrong and fail to mention this simple concept of posts backs re-setting all loaded scripts? I not seen this mentioned anywhere. Why is such a large spectacular point is left out in the large number of code samples that ALL TEST for the script being loaded? Clearly those tons of examples and books have sample code written in a stupid way.

Comment: Without seeing the examples you mention its hard to say but one way around it is to use an update panel that is part of the AJAX Extensions in visual studio. If you put your label and button inside the update panel then you will get your expected behavior. But the event handler for the button will not be able to change anything outside the update panel.

Comment: Thanks kindly Mike. I appreciate you pointing out the post back issue. I think it should be common knowledge (and I am learning). However, when the same example places a vb.net (asp) button on the web form with some vb.net code then leaving out the post back issue is my main beef. (the test for loaded scrip will thus never run). As you note, much better to just place a button on the form that runs jscrip in the browser without a round trip or vb event code – but I needed the "key" explain that the post back re-sets the injected scripts. And yes I see examples suggesting to use frame or panel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consolidating(and elaborating on) the comments on the original question here.

The issue is that ASP.NET buttons cause full post backs to the server everytime they are clicked and when a page does a full postback it resets all scripts that may have been registered from previous actions. This means that any script that was registered the last time the button was clicked will be wiped out and the page will not know anything about it the second time around.

There are a few ways to get around this.

1. UpdatePanel: My prefered way is to declare all your controls that need to be manipulated in the button click handler inside an AJAX Update Panel like:

   ```
   <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
       <ContentTemplate>
           <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
           <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
       </ContentTemplate>
   </asp:UpdatePanel>
   ```

   What this does is limits what the button can change when it is clicked and causes a post back. In order to use this you will also need to declare a Scriptmanager anywhere before the updatepanel. When you register the script you will need to use that scriptmanagers `RegisterScriptControl` function.
2. Manual AJAX Postback: Another way to accomplish this would be to use a "manual" AJAX call. I've done this a few times but it is much more complex than the update panel version and I'm not sure if the way that I've done it is the "right" way to go about it. First you will change you ASP button to a regular HTML input button. On the HTML button the `onclick` should be a javasciprt function that you designate. Inside the javascript function you will need to go through the process of declaring an XMLHttpRequst object. [This site](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_create.asp) goes over how to use the object pretty thoroughly. The way that I have gotten information back and forth is by using the headers attached to the request/response. You need to add them using `setRequestHeader` function and get them from the `getAllResponseHeaders` function. Once you get into the page load event on the server side you will need to evaluate the headers of the request and if one exists that signifies that the button was clicked(which you will need to add manually) then you can call a function and add a header to the response that will tell the javascript what to display in the pop up box. I'm sure using headers isn't the best method for getting inormation back and forth but if you are just talking about booleans that only dictate what to print to the user then you probably don't need to go through the process of setting up a JSON or XML response. This is also assuming that you are doing more on the server side than just checking how many times the button has been clicked because if thats all you need to do you should use option 3.
3. The simplest way to accomplish this would be to make the entire thing a javascript function. Declare a variable(int) on the page and set it to 0 on load. Then when the button is clicked you would just need to check the counter, if its greater than 0 display one message, if its 0 then display a different message. This will only work if your condition is very basic(it can get very complex but sometimes thats overkill).

So, In my opinion, those three options should be able to handle whatever you need to do. The first is very simple to use, the second is very versatile and can become very powerful if you implement XML or JSON in your communications with the server and the third is much faster than communicating with the server every time. Deciding which will be the best fit is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

You did not add the script tag to enclose your script.

*Adding function*

```
strScript = "<script type=\"text/javascript\">";
strScript = "function MyMsg()"
strScript += "{"
strScript += "alert(document.getElementById('TextBox3').value);"
strScript += "}"
strScript = "</script>";
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "MyMsg", strScript, True)
```

Calling function

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "MyCall", "<script type=\"text/javascript\">MyMsg();</script>", True)
```

Comment: Does the final boolean of the `ClientScript.registerstartupscript` not add the script tags anyway?

Comment: The code works + runs fine. And as pointed out, using "true" adds the script tags anyway. So how and why then does the code run just fine? Worse, it still doesn't answer why testing for registered never works - I always get the not registered text.